# Using LLVM linker when using Clang & CMake

Tags: linker, cmake, clang

What's the best way to tell CMake to use the LLVM linker `llvm-link` instead of GNU `ld` as linker? When configuring a project with

```
CXX=clang++ cmake <args>
```

the default linker appears to be untouched, remaining `usr/bin/ld` (on Linux).

Is this possible without [using a separate toolchain file](http://mhungerford.blogspot.com/2010/10/cmake-and-clangllvm-fun.html)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274328/69663 seems related

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This turns out to be unrelated to CMake: `clang++` uses the system linker by default. For example,

```
echo "#include <atomic>\n int main() { return 0; }" \
    | clang++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -
```

uses `/usr/bin/ld` to link the application. To change the linker to `llvm-link`, one needs to first emit LLVM byte code, and then call the linker, e.g.:

```
echo "#include <atomic>\n int main() { return 0; }" \
    | clang++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -S -emit-llvm -o - - \
    | llvm-link -o binary -
```

This bypasses `/usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: When you say the 'system linker' do you mean the one that it finds first in your `$PATH`, or is it hardcoded into clang to use the one in `/usr/bin/`?

Comment: Clang hardcodes the linker search path, AFAIK, and attempts to pick up the `ld` binary in other places besides your `$PATH`. I said "system linker" to refer to the standard linker of native object code as opposed to the LLVM byte code linker.

Comment: @orian: Check out this example: http://git.icir.org/binpacpp.git/blob/HEAD:/cmake/EnableLLVM.cmake

Answer (score 6):

As of 3.4, `clang` looks for the linker (`ld`) at `GCCInstallation.getParentLibPath() + "/../" + GCCInstallation.getTriple().str() + "/bin"` before it looks for `ld` on the path.  You should be able to put your linker in `/usr/lib/gcc/<arch><sub>-<vendor>-<sys>-<abi>/<version>/ld` and have it called by `clang` in 1 step.  To specify this location manually, use the *undocumented* `-B` flag.  Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to alter the name of the linker that is searched for so using ld.gold or lld is going to require a symlink at the aforementioned location.