# Unable to Change Default Linker in CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, clang

I am trying to change my linker to ld.gold so that I can build LLVM and
CLANG faster. I have changed my environment variable with:

```
export LD=ld.gold
```

and I have changed CMAKE_LINKER in ccmake to /usr/bin/ld.gold. However,
when I generate the files, my linker is detected as GNU ld. Running top
during compilation confirms that ld is running rather than gold.

When editing the CMake Link Executable variable to:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_LINKER=/usr/bin/ld.gold -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="<CMAKE_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>" -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
```

I receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: -Werror=date-time: unknown option
/usr/bin/ld.gold: use the --help option for usage information
utils/PerfectShuffle/CMakeFiles/llvm-PerfectShuffle.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'bin/llvm-PerfectShuffle' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/llvm-PerfectShuffle] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:13983: recipe for target 'utils/PerfectShuffle/CMakeFiles/llvm-PerfectShuffle.dir/all' failed
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, but I have had the same problem on Arch Linux.

Thank You.

Comment: I specifid that setting the CMAKE_LINKER variable did not work, which is the solution to that quesiton.

Comment: It is `CMAKE_{C,CXX}_LINK_EXECUTABLE`.

Comment: Read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274328/3440745) carefully: aside from `CMAKE_LINKER` it specifies `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable.

Comment: I specified that it did not help in the edit.

Comment: So your linker doesn't support option `-Werror=date-time`. Because this is actually a **compiler** option, you may try to remove `<FLAGS>` from `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` definition.

Comment: Removing `<FLAGS>` gives me the error `ld.gold: -Wl, -allow-shlib-undefined: unknown option`. I've tried almost every permutation of variables possible now, with no luck.

Answer (score 18):

`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-fuse-ld=gold` will pass `-fuse-ld=gold` to the compiler, which will properly use the gold linker.