# ld: unknown option: --sysroot=/Users/myname/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on macOS trying to build Android native source code using pure **cmake** command instead of the gradle external native build scripts. Below is the command I use to compile my Android C/C++ code:

```sh
➜ /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake \
-DCMAKE_LINKER=/Users/myname/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/myname/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DANDROID_STL=c++_static \
-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/myname/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r20b \
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23 \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja \
-G"Android Gradle - Ninja" \
..
```

By running above command, i always got below errors:

> ```sh
> Run Build  
> Command:"/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja"
> "cmTC_2af97"
>
>   [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2af97.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
>
>   [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_2af97
>
> ld: unknown option:  
> --sysroot=/Users/myname/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot
>
>
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
> invocation)
>
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>
>
>   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
> ```

After searching around, it looks like the `ld` linker from my macOS overwrites my NDK's `ld` linker. I have tried to pass the NDK linker `ld` via CMake argument as said in [cmake-use-a-custom-linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867745/cmake-use-a-custom-linker) by specifying below option to cmake:

```sh
-DCMAKE_LINKER=/Users/myname/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r20b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld
```

but still got above same error `ld: unknown option: --sysroot xxx`.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to solve this error? Appreciate your help.

---

Similar questions asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/1446914/ndk-r20-embedded-toolchain-fails-on-macos but not got answer yet.

Comment: The answer you refer to also suggests modifying the `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable with the new linker executable and flags. Did you do this?

Comment: @squareskittles, thanks for your reply, i just tired with `-DCMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE="<CMAKE_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>" ` and `-DCMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE="<CMAKE_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>"` , both don't work and have the same errors seen.

Comment: Please add this information to your question post, showing what values you substituted for each individual variable, such as `<CMAKE_LINKER>`, `<FLAGS>`, `<CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS>`, etc.

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#variables) for Android toolchain describes `ANDROID_LD` option. You may try to set it to `lld`. By itself, variable `CMAKE_LINKER` has no meaning for CMake compilation/linking process. Setting `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` could have a sense, but I don't sure whether CMake passes it to `try_compile` process in case of custom toolchain is used.