# is there an environment variable I can passs to cmake that will make clang use lld and not ld?

Tags: clang, lld

is there an environment variable I can passs to cmake that will make clang use lld and not ld?

I want something that I can use with CC and CXX and will accomplish the same thing as fuse-ld=lld.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: use a custom linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867745/cmake-use-a-custom-linker)